# Show information after mouseover on image using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, xmlhttprequest

I have three Pictures on a Website that are generated this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AJAX</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/stil.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"        src="lib/js/ajaxeinsendeaufgabe2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Zusatzinformationen</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="img" src="img/b1.jpg" />
            </td>
            <td id="info0"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="img" src="img/b2.jpg" />
            </td>
            <td id="info1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="img" src="img/b3.jpg"/>
            </td>
            <td id="info2"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

My Problem: how do i show text when i move with the mouse over one of the three images. Each Image must display unique text.

Here is an incomplete part of the Code:

```
var resOb = new XMLHttpsRequest ();
window.onload = function () {
document.getElementsByTagName("img").onmouseover =
function sndReq(i){
switch (i) {
case 0:
resOb.open('get', 'info0.txt', true);
break;

case 1:
resOb.open('get', 'info1.txt', true);
break;


case 2:
resOb.open('get', 'info2.txt', true);
break;

resOb.onreadystatechange = function (){
    handleResponse (i);
}
```

How i can generate the text information for each image using onmouseover event?

Comment: you mean when i mouse hover on img/b1.jpg it wil display <td id="info0"></td> ?

Comment: @MannanBahelim Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="img" src="img/b1.jpg" data-id='0'/>
            </td>
            <td id="info0"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="img" src="img/b2.jpg" data-id='1'/>
            </td>
            <td id="info1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="img" src="img/b3.jpg" data-id='2'/>
            </td>
            <td id="info2"></td>
        </tr>
    </table> 





 $( ".img" ).mouseover(function() {
       var resOb = new XMLHttpsRequest ();
       resOb.open('get', 'info'+ $(this).attr('data-id') +'.txt', true);
    });
```

Comment: your info is coming from .txt file. right ? so you can change the text from that file but dont change the file name. i.e [ info{i}.txt ]